# Modal Popup box with bootstrap from code behind

Tags: c#, .net, modal-dialog, modalpopups, modal-popup

I have the requirement of using modal popups with bootstrap.

I want to call it from the code behind to display a successful message without using ajax.

Comment: What did you try for this? Share some code.

Comment: try writing the javascript function for calling the popup modal then search how to call javascript function with asp.net.

Comment: Basically lost a bunch of hours trying to get ajax to work on my project w/o any success. Think I saw something about a dummy hidden box for control to call from my c# method. Am I on the right way?